# True or false ? Abel theorem in the complex case

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series, divergent-series

Let $a_k $ be **complex** numbers such that the radius of convergence of $\sum a_k z^k$ is $1$.

Suppose $|\sum_{k=0}^{N} a_k |\longrightarrow  +\infty $ as $N\to +\infty$.

Then, is it true that $$\lim_{z\to 1,\, z\in \mathbb R}\left| \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} a_k z^k \right|=+\infty\,? $$

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/288432/limit-power-series-at-boundary?lq=1), the question was answered for real $a_k$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I can't come up with a counterexample but the proof in the real case breaks down!

Comment: If you take the modulus of the partial sums, you already have real counterexamples. Say $a_k = (-1)^k\cdot (k+1)$.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is a very nice counterexample :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can have

$$\Biggl\lvert \sum_{k = 0}^{N} a_k\Biggr\rvert \to +\infty$$

even if

$$f(z) = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} a_kz^k$$

has an analytic continuation to a neighbourhood of $1$, which clearly implies that $f(z)$ remains bounded as $z \to 1$. One of the simplest examples is $f(z) = \frac{1}{(1+z)^2}$, which has the Maclaurin series

$$\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} (-1)^k(k+1)z^k\,.$$

The partial sums of the coefficients are

$$\sum_{k = 0}^{N} (-1)^k(k+1) = (-1)^{N}\biggl\lfloor \frac{N+2}{2}\biggr\rfloor\,.$$

If however

$$\sum_{k = 0}^N a_k$$

tends to $\infty$ in a specific direction, say

$$\lim_{N \to \infty} \operatorname{Re} e^{-i\varphi}\sum_{k = 0}^{N} a_k = +\infty\,,$$

then it follows that

$$\lim_{\substack{z \to 1 \\ z \in (0,1)}} \operatorname{Re} e^{-i\varphi}f(z) = +\infty\,.$$

This is an easy consequence of the real case of course.